# Must I void or destroy a check after using its check number online?

Tags: united-states, check, checking-account

The online banking system I use to pay my car loans requires checking account number, routing number, and a check number. If I use a check number from a real check in my checkbook, should I then void or destroy the paper check, or is it still usable?

Additional info per request: I’m using Huntington bank (USA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine.  Check numbers are for your benefit only; the bank doesn't care about them.

Comment: This may not be *universally* true. My bank [says](https://www.simple.com/help/articles/getting-started/checks) "Please note that eChecks and paper checks printed by another company with your Simple account and routing numbers will not work. Our accounts do not support having checks drawn off them.", for example. I'm not sure what they use to reject third-party printed checks, but the number not matching up may be one factor.

Comment: That seems like your account just doesn't honor any checks.

Comment: @xyious I am able to send checks via online bill pay. These come with my account numbers on them, as a normal check would. (I know this because I've had one sent to me to pass along to a vendor.)